# Is it possible to summarize repetitive code in python?

Tags: python

I have been trying to make an application in python in which you can choose fonts for a text, for this I have an excel in which I have 347 cells with a font name in each one. The problem is that I have to extract the information of each one of those cells and store it in a variable and this is very slow.

For this I have used the following code:

```py
# Excel file with all the fonts
fonts_excel = 'Fonts.xlsx'

workbook = load_workbook(fonts_excel) # Load the entire workbook.

worksheet = workbook['Sheet1'] # Load the worksheet in which the fonts are on
all_rows = list(workbook.rows) # Load all the rows of thw worksheet

# Load all the cells
for cell in all_rows[1]:
    font1 = cell.value # Cell 1
for cell in all_rows[2]:
    font2 = cell.value # Cell 2
for cell in all_rows[3]:
    font3 = cell.value # Cell 3
for cell in all_rows[4]:
    font4 = cell.value # Cell 4
for cell in all_rows[5]:
    font5 = cell.value # Cell 5
for cell in all_rows[6]:
    font6 = cell.value # Cell 6
for cell in all_rows[7]:
    font7 = cell.value # Cell 7
for cell in all_rows[8]:
    font8 = cell.value # Cell 8
for cell in all_rows[9]:
    font9 = cell.value # Cell 9
for cell in all_rows[10]:
    font10 = cell.value # Cell 10
for cell in all_rows[11]:
    font11 = cell.value # Cell 11
for cell in all_rows[12]:
    font12 = cell.value # Cell 12
for cell in all_rows[13]:
    font13 = cell.value # Cell 13
for cell in all_rows[14]:
    font14 = cell.value # Cell 14
for cell in all_rows[15]:
    font15 = cell.value # Cell 15
for cell in all_rows[16]:
    font16 = cell.value # Cell 16
for cell in all_rows[17]:
    font17 = cell.value # Cell 17
for cell in all_rows[18]:
    font18 = cell.value # Cell 18
for cell in all_rows[19]:
    font19 = cell.value # Cell 19
for cell in all_rows[20]:
    font20 = cell.value # Cell 20
for cell in all_rows[21]:
    font21 = cell.value # Cell 21
for cell in all_rows[22]:
    font22 = cell.value # Cell 22
for cell in all_rows[23]:
    font23 = cell.value # Cell 23
for cell in all_rows[24]:
    font24 = cell.value # Cell 24
for cell in all_rows[25]:
    font25 = cell.value # Cell 25
for cell in all_rows[26]:
    font26 = cell.value # Cell 26
for cell in all_rows[27]:
    font27 = cell.value # Cell 27
for cell in all_rows[28]:
    font28 = cell.value # Cell 28
for cell in all_rows[29]:
    font29 = cell.value # Cell 29
for cell in all_rows[30]:
    font30 = cell.value # Cell 30
```

What I want is to be able to put the 347 sources without having to do the whole `for cell in all_rows[1]...` process. Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: use an array for the fonts, then a loop to fill the array?

Comment: Why are you looping over the row like `for cell in all_rows[10]` and then assigning the cell value to the same variable over and over again like `font10 = cell.value`? That's just going to assign only the very last cell value of the row `all_rows[10]` to that variable. Maybe that's what you ultimately want, but repeatedly setting values and then overwriting them is inefficient and makes no sense.

Comment: @DaveS How do I do tha? I am new in python and I don't really know how to do it.

Comment: @RandomDavis And what should I do not to do it?

Comment: Maybe you should explain how you intend to use the fonts you've captured later on in your code... Otherwise its kinda hard to know what you really need...

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted equivalent code to yours, the simplest thing would be to store the fonts in a list. But the way your code works, you're looping through each cell in each row, and setting the variable's value to each cell's value, overwriting the previous value of that variable, until the last cell in that row is reached in the loop.

So, assuming you actually want to have the last cell value in each row be the font value, you would just access the index of the last cell in each row like:

```
fonts = []

for row in all_rows:
    fonts.append(row[-1]) # [-1] is the last item's index
```

Or, if you wanted to import every cell in every row, you'd do:

```
fonts = []

for row in all_rows:
    for cell in row:
        fonts.append(cell)
```

It's not exactly clear to me what you're asking for, but hopefully that's clear enough to help you, still. If you shared example data then it would make it a lot more obvious what you're trying to do.

---

If you want to store them in a `dict` so you can reference them by name, you'd do something like:

```
fonts = {}

for i in range(len(all_rows)):
    fonts['font' + str(i)] = row[-1]
```

That way, you can access fonts like `fonts['font1']`. But I don't really see a point of doing that at all. It's much easier to access them like just `fonts[1]`.

Comment: That's more or less what I want, but I would like to save each cell in a variable so that I can then for example do `print(font1)`, I don't know if you understand me.

Comment: You could just do `print(fonts[1])` that way. Dynamically creating and referring to hundreds of variables is a terrible practice and is an anti-pattern. You could use a `dict` though, I'll write an example. But it still wouldn't really make sense or help you at all.

Comment: If you just saved the fonts to an array as suggested you could print font12 by doing something like `print(fonts[11])`...

Comment: `fontDict = {f'font{rowIdx}':all_rows[rowIdx][-1] for rowIdx in range(len(all_rows))}`

Comment: Thank you very much, with your help I have made a variable that contains all the fonts as a list and as you said, now I can easily `print(fonts_list[23])` and it shows me the name of the font that is in that row.